# Programmatically call textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield

The current project runs under cocos2d v2.

I have a simple UITextField added to a CCLayer.

Whenever, the user touch the textField, a keyboard appears.

Then when the user touch the "return" button, the keyboard disappear and clears the input.

What I tried to do is to make the same thing when the user touches anywhere outside the UITextField.

I did find a method and it works :

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.view.tag != kTAGTextField){
        [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] viewWithTag:kTAGTextField] resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

However, this method doesn't call the function :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

I use this function to do some calculation and clear the input. Therefore, I would like ccTouchesBegan to enter this textFieldShouldReturn when the textfield is "resignFirstResponder".

Comment: BabyAzerty did you find a way how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a):

> **textFieldShouldReturn:**
>   Asks the delegate if the text field should process the pressing of the return button.

So it is only called when the user taps the return button.

I would rather create a method for the calculation and input clearing, and call that method whenever you want it to be called. Example:

```
- (void)calculateAndClearInput {
    // Do some calculations and clear the input.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Call your calculation and clearing method.
    [self calculateAndClearInput];
    return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.view.tag != kTAGTextField) {
        [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] viewWithTag:kTAGTextField] resignFirstResponder];
        // Call it here as well.
        [self calculateAndClearInput];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an issue where only the textFieldShouldReturn: method is not called. It calls every other delegate method like textFieldDidEndEditing:. Can you please help me,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474328/textfieldshouldreturn-is-not-called-but-textfielddidendediting-gets-called?noredirect=1#comment68199491_40474328

Answer (score 1):

As @matsr suggested, you should consider reorganising your program logic. It doesn't make sense for `resignFirstResponder` on a UITextField to call `textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`, because often resignFirstResponder is called from within that method. In addition you shouldn't attempt to programmatically call `textFieldShouldReturn`.

Instead I suggest moving your calculation code into a new method in your controller/whatever and calling that both in `textFieldShouldReturn` and when you handle the touch where you call `resignFirstResponder` on the UITextField.

This also helps achieve decoupling of your event handling code from your calculation/logic code.