# textFieldShouldReturn: is not called but textFieldDidEndEditing: gets called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a textfield in a UIAlertController and I am trying to implement the delegate method textFieldShouldReturn: which doesn't get called. But i tried implementing the method textFieldDidEndEditing: which gets called without any problem. Please help me here. This is how i do it,

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField
    *textField) {
            textField.placeholder = @"Product upc";
            textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
            textField.delegate = weakSelf;

        }];

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"textfield should return");
    //do something
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSLog(@"end editing ");
}
```

Comment: I tried , ` - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` which also works

Comment: because you `return NO;`. If `return NO` is mean it not run to it. `textFieldShouldReturn` action when u click on return of keybroad.
`textFieldDidEndEditing` action when u click out sight of text field

Comment: i changed the return type to YES still it doesn't get called